# Get Upper 4bits of a byte

Tags: delphi, byte, bit

I am trying to get the upper 4 bits of a `Byte`.

That is my attempt so far:

```
function Upper4Bits(const X : Byte): Byte;
type 
   BS = set of 0..7;
var 
   K : Byte; Q: BS;
begin
  Q := [];
  for K := 0 to 3 do {is it right? upper?}
    {what i need here?}
    Include(Q, {what i put here});

  Upper4Bits := Byte(Q)
end;
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: in what form do you want these bits?

Comment: as Byte, just take 4 upper bits and turn them to one byte

Comment: @Ismail: That is *exactly* what the code `X shr 4` does. (If you want the lower four bytes instead, you have to do `X and $F` instead.)

Comment: @Ismail, David: Just to clarify - `1101 1011 shr 4 = 0000 1101 = 1101` while `1101 1011 and $F0 = 1101 1011 and 1111 0000 = 1101 0000`.

Comment: After taking Upper 4 byte of Byte1 and Lower4 Bytes of Byte3
how to put them in Q: is this true:
  Include(Q, Byte1 shr 4);
  Include(Q, Byte3 and $F);  ?

Comment: `(b1 and $f0) or (b3 and $0f)`

Comment: @Ismail,  Even though it is valid to write `Upper4Bits := Byte(Q)`, it's the first time I ever see someone do it (I almost forgot it was legal syntax). It's more "standard" in Delphi to use the implicit variable Result.  `Result := Byte(Q)`

Comment: @Ken: I do that too every now and then.

Comment: @Ken, it is not only legal. Besides being the way it is described in the Pascal User Manual and Report, it has been the only way to assign a function result for a long time in Pascal.

Comment: Well, looks like I'm too young to have known that era :P.  Like I said, I never quite saw this syntax in code before except back in school. I find using "Result" far less confusing. But then again, at that point, it's more a matter of preferences.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to your comment to kotlinski's answer, you want `result := (byte1 and $F0) or (byte3 and $0F)`.

Comment: So the OP wants the upper four bits of one byte, and the lowerfour bits of another byte, not merely the upper four bits moved over with shr.   Wish the OP would spend some time asking his question more precisely.

Comment: Indeed! I actually found out by one of his comments.

Comment: Well I upvoted your answer, and downvoted the question, because it's a good answer, to a useless question. If the OP edited the question so it was not useless, then I would remove the downvote.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Comment: +1 for stealing my idea and making a PNG of it! (Just too bad you confused left and right.)

Comment: Also +1 for the PNG.  Appropriate use of graphics helped a lot, and IMO, should be done more often here on SO.

Comment: (@PhiS: That was precisely what I was saying...)

Comment: Please fix this image. It's got 3 upvotes but it is very weak. As well as the shl/shr error, the arrows point to the middle of the result in both cases. And there's no `or` to combine things. And the shift approach is wrong too since OP wants top 4 from b1 and bottom 4 from b3 combined.

Comment: @Ian, fixed the shl->shr in the image.

Comment: @johan good work but look at the accepted answer and see how it differs.

Comment: @David, I did notice, but I feel it's not up to me to change the nature of Ian's answer, I just fixed the obvious errors

Comment: @Johan I understand. It's a shame because it has the potential to be the best answer!

Comment: i didn't realize i had a shr/shl bug. At the same time i really didn't understand the original poster's question. He wanted the upper four bits - so he could have them...either he wanted them as `1111xxxx` (with the lower four bits set to zero), or he wanted the upper four bits moved to the lower four bits position. After that i (still) don't see that he wanted bits from two different bytes combined. So i was just trying to point out the tools he can use to solve whatever wider problem he was having.

Answer (score 3):

How about `Upper4Bits := X Shr 4;`?

Comment: i have this:
 _____byte 1_____   byte2_    _____byte 3_____   byte4_

0000          0000-00000000  0000          0000-00000000
 
Upper4Bits    12Bits         Lower4Bits    12Bits
  
I want to take Upper4Bits of Byte1 and Lower4Bits of Byte3
and Make them 1 Byte
i think my question now is clear.

Comment: This comment should be put in your question. Your question is useless as it is, as you accepted an answer that makes no sense given your question alone.